# Programming in C-Game

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, 2d

All i want is sto fill in the B array with 30 random 1s that are not the one next to each other and not on the first or last lines, neither on the first or last row. I'm trying to do that by creating another array named empodia so that i will get there random numbers ( formated so that they will be in the borders of the B array) but i cant do it properly. i dont want to do it with pointers though. Thanks for your help!

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #define N 23
    #define M 79
    int main()
    {
        int i,j,a,b,epilogi,seira,stili;
        char A[N][M];
        int B[N][M],empodia[15][2];
        srand(time(NULL));

        for(a=0;a<15;a++)
        {
            for(b=0;b<2;b++)
            {
              do{
              seira=2+rand()%18; //i want to get a random number from 2-20
              stili=2+rand()%76;  //i want to get a random number from 2-77
              }while(B[seira][stili]==1 || B[seira-1][stili-1]==1 || B[seira-1][stili+1]==1 || B[seira+1][stili-1]==1 || B[seira+1][stili+1]==1 || B[seira][stili-1]==1 || B[seira][stili+1]==1 || B[seira-1][stili]==1 || B[seira+1][stili]==1);  //so that i will not get numbers one next to each other

               empodia[a][0]= seira;
               empodia[a][b+1]=stili;
               B[seira][stili]=1;
            }
        }

        for (i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
            for (j=0;j<M;j++)
            {
                if((i==0) || (j==M))
                {
                B[i][j]= 1;
                }
                else if ((i==N) || (j==0))
                {
                    B[i][j]= 1;
                }
                 else if ((i==N-1)|| (j==M))
                {
                    B[i][j]= 1;
                }
                 else if ((i==N) || (j==M-1))
                {
                    B[i][j]= 1;
                }

                else if(B[i][j]!=1)
                {
                    B[i][j]= 0;
                }
            }
        }

        for (i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
            for (j=0;j<M;j++)
            {
                printf("%d",B[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What is the precise meaning of "next to each other"?  Does every adjacent cell (including diagonal ones) counts as "next to each other?"

Comment: Using single-letter macros is very dangerous. In genral, youz should avoid such names also for other code at file-level. Use more descriptive names instead.

Comment: Bluestar: yes even tthe diagonal ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for such interesting problem. here is my code which should work. don't forget to memset the `col` array everytime before running the operation.

```
bool col[N+3][M+3];  ///a color array to check availability
int rrr[]= {1,1,0,-1,-1,-1,0,1}; ///8 direction
int ccc[]= {0,1,1,1,0,-1,-1,-1}; ///8 direction

for(int i=0; i<30; i++){  ///for 30 random numbers
    while(1){  ///loop to detect a random available position
        int xx,yy;
        xx = 2+rand()%18;
        yy = 2+rand()%76;
        if(!col[xx][yy]){  ///checking availability
            B[xx][yy]=1;   ///setting 1
            col[xx][yy]=true;         ///making all the neighboring
            for(int j=0; j<8; j++){   ///points unavailable
                col[xx+rrr[j]][yy+ccc[j]]=true;
            }
            break; ///break when finds an available position
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what if we are at the N+3 of the bool array?

Comment: will never be there. because we are modding the random values by `18` and `76` which are at least `3` less than `N & M` @D.Gial

Comment: Sorry, i still get 1s one under the other or diagonal ones

Comment: are you running it again and again without memsetting ??

Comment: i dont know how to do that

Comment: Can you explain me how to do memsetting?

Comment: Simply  assign all the value in the `col` array to `false`

Comment: Could you sent me your full code?cause problem exists thank you for your patience